# How to split text and save it in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to programming and having some trouble reading in a huge text file and splitting up the text data.

Each entry from the text file looks as follows:

```
61.111.15.70 - - [17/Jan/2014:15:14:21 +0200] "GET /dean-martins-almeida-850322ejsapi=1&videoFinishedEvent=onsport-inc-usdot-850322.php HTTP/1.0" 302 533 "-" "http://www.checkprivacy.or.kr:6600/RS/PRIVACY_ENFAQ.jsp"
 Reason: "Detects JavaScript DOM/miscellaneous properties and methods"
```

I wish to read in the text file and then split up the data as follows:

**client_ip:** 61.111.15.70

**date_time:** [17/Jan/2014:15:14:21 +0200]

**http_request:** "GET /dean-martins-almeida-850322ejsapi=1&videoFinishedEvent=onsport-inc-usdot-850322.php HTTP/1.0"

**http_response_code:** 302

**unknown_1:** 533

**referer:** "http://www.checkprivacy.or.kr:6600/RS/PRIVACY_ENFAQ.jsp"

**reason:** "Detects JavaScript DOM/miscellaneous properties and methods"

I am at a total loss as to how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'd parse it step by step. Look for chars or strings ("Landmarks") that will occur in all of the strings you expect and in what relation they are to the stuff you are interested in. For the IP it's easy: It begins at the beginning and ends where the first " " occurs.

```
var ip = myText.TakeWhile(c => c!=' ').ToString();
```

The date is in brackets.

```
var date = myText.SkipWhile(c1 => c1 !='[').TakeWhile(c2 => c2!=']').ToString();
```

The request strarts with a quotation mark. So you do the above search for '"'. So you go on until you have all the info you need extracted.

Comment: Thank you Einer! I will implement this and see if I manage to get the results.

Comment: I was also wondering, wouldn't it be better to use regular expressions rather than lamda expressions? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: That depends... I find them rather hard to read/debug. On the other hand they are pretty mighty... Personally I go for readability!